# How do I implement a scrollBy() function in Qt's QWebEngine?

Tags: c++, qt, scrollbar, chromium, qtwebengine

I want to have the QWebEngine's scrollBar scroll up and down with a dial. Older versions of Qt had this function with the QWebView.scroll(int). How do I implement this functionality in a QWebEngine?

I started by using the simplebrowser template included with Qt 5.12.

I have already tried running

```
QWebEngineView()->page()->runJavaScript(QString("window.scrollTo(%1, %2);").arg(scrollX).arg(scrollY));
```

Found [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/60091/scroll-a-qwebengineview/4).

But that wasn't working. I have also tried setting the focus to the WebPage and  having the code simulate a page down key press. That didn't work either.

Here is the WebView's onDialChanged(int) funtion. It is called when the dial on the browserwindow changes.

```
int WebView::previousDial = 0;
int WebView::diff = 0;

void WebView::onDialChanged(int value) {
     int diff = value - this->previousDial;
     this->previousDial = value;
     std::cout << diff << std::endl;
     if(diff > 0) {
         this->setFocus();
         this->page()->runJavaScript(QString("window.scrollTo(%1, %2);").arg(0).arg(500), QWebEngineScript::ApplicationWorld);
     }
     else {
         this->setFocus();
         this->page()->runJavaScript(QString("window.scrollTo(%1, %2);").arg(0).arg(500), QWebEngineScript::ApplicationWorld);
         }
}
```

Right now it is only scrolling by 500 for testing purposes. Once I get it working I will have the scroll distance based on value.

I expect that when the dial changes that the page will scroll down by 500 pixels. When I run the program it doesn't scroll and I get the message `DuplicateHandle failed: Access is denied`

Am I supposed to use a QWebChannel to do this? Or do I use qt.window.scrollBy() instead?

I'm starting to think that this isn't possible yet with Qt. I might just remake my project with electron.